# What are some good resources for learning Synfig Studio?

Tags: animation, synfig-studio

I am new to Synfig and am facing issues in understanding how to proceed with the application. Can you share some resources which can help me getting started with Synfig-studio. Or can you suggest some other tools for 2D animation which has support for Linux.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is meant to be a "replacement" for flash, at least to act similar to it, so look for tutorials on flash.

One important thing in learning any application is to define your own objectives. First general objectives, but in reality, you need to define a step by step learning process.

1. How do I import this asset.
2. How do I move this asset from a to b.
3. How do I control how this move looks.
4. Etc.

---

Edited. Of course this is after reading the documentation the oficial website has: http://synfig.org/